# Resharper - Benefits

Tags: resharper

Having seen a few mentions about Resharper on this site and on SO, I thought I would take a look.  There seems to be a hell of a lot of documentation on their website, so I was just wondering, in a snapshot, what benefits it brings and what are the main reasons people use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Speed. It makes a lot of things *much* quicker.

My favourite features are the code navigation, which are a huge time savers.

The refactorings are handy, but VS itself is catching up in that area.

I also use it with the awesome StyleCop for Resharper plugin for more painless StyleCopping. (This is now incorporated in to StyleCop itself. See http://stylecop.codeplex.com/ for more info.)

I suggest you download the trail and give it a go, virtually everyone I know who has tried it has been impressed, but not everyone, some people don't get on with it.

Comment: The irony is that often ReSharper slows me down, waiting for popups to appear, but I probably should just get a new laptop. :)

Comment: Yep, R# + VS2010 requires a pretty decent spec machine...

Comment: I hate coding without it now.  And it's great to be able to open an old file, see the orange down the right side, and quickly clean up the code.  And having a tool set the rules, keeps people from arguing about what good style is.

Comment: I think i'll give it a try, then if I like it I may as well take advantage of the student discount.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Resharper makes coding more **enjoyable**.

You have to try it yourself to get a feel for it, a feature summary doesn't do it justice.

Answer (score 2):

IMO: [Coding Assistance](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html) is the best feature of the Resharper.

A fast look at [features](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html) will give you the picture.